# min-height css issue when using AngularJS Routing

Tags: css, angularjs, ngroute

I have the following configuration in a simple **html** file:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {

  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 1em
}

.b1 {
  background: #2AC56D
}
.b2 {
  background: #fae10c
}
.b3 {
  background: #03a9f4
}
```

```html
<section class="b1">1
</section>
<section class="b2">2
</section>
<section class="b3">3
</section>
```

Then I try to use AngularJS Routing in the following way: the section elements go into a template called **template.html** like this:

```
<section class="b1">1
</section>
<section class="b2">2
</section>
<section class="b3">3
</section>
```

And I add to the main file the AngularJS, the **ng-route** dependencies and the following script like this:

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

It is working on the scripting part, but the **section** elements are no longer full height and look like this.

[image]

What is really the issue and, more important, how can I correct it? What I really need is to have some **div**'s or **section**'s at least full screen height.

Thank you.

Comment: is section element direct descendant from body?

Comment: As you can see, in the first case, it is, but in the latter, it is descendant on the **ng-view** div.

Comment: give your `<div  data-ng-view>` height 100%.It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, To make `height: 100%;` work properly, you need to set in its parent div too.

Suppose this html:

```
<div id="main">
  <section>1</section>
</div>
```

Then just applying 100% height in section won't work. You need to set fixed height for the parent element. So, use:

```
#main{
  height: 100%;
}
```

You already set 100% height in html,body tag that's good.

---

So, in your case, apply like this:

```
div[data-ng-view]{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And it worked for the first case. But in the latter, I forgot to add it to the ng-view **div**. Now it works.

Comment: Sorry unclear with your updated question. Can you please visualize?

Comment: I hope the latter image helps.

Comment: Hmm, Add clear both on footer. `footer{clear: both;}`

Comment: may be I'm not understanding.